# VB.net linq .contains on XML column

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, linq

I have a database with one XML column named Results.
This column contains results from factory testing and different XML formatting depending on which test was performed.

I'm developing a GUI where I can browse my results so I need to filter this column dynamically.

My first idea was to use `Results.contains("myfilter")` but this does not seem to work.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with linq and entities.

This is my query:

```
Using context As New Entities
    Dim query = From tr In context.TestResults
                Join t In context.Tests On a Equals tr.Tests
                Join ts In context.TestStations On ts Equals tr.TestStations
                Join ut In context.UnitTraveler On ut Equals tr.UnitTraveler
                Where t.Id = TestID
                Where ts.Id = TestStationID
                Where tr.Results.Contains("TestCurrent")
                Take Count
                Select ut.SerialNumber, ut.ModelString, ut.Passed, tr.Results, tr.StartedOn, tr.EndedOn
                Order By StartedOn Descending
End Using
```

Update 2015-12-01: I still haven't found a solution to this. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Since [XML data type in SQL mapped to `XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_5) in .NET, I'd try : `Where tr.Results.ToString().Contains("TestCurrent")` (not sure if `XElement.ToString()` is supported by LINQ-to-SQL though)

Comment: This does not work. Neither does tr.Results.toString Like "%TestCurrent%" or tr.Results.toString Like "**TestCurrent**"

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Results` property is of type `String` and you search inside this string for a specific substring you can use this:

```
query = (From tr In ... Where tr.Results Like "*TestCurrent*")
```

If Results it is a collection or List

```
query = (From tr In ... Where tr.Results.Find(Function(f As Result) f.Contents Like "*TestCurrent*") IsNot Nothing)
```

Please change the used words Result and Contents according to your Classnames and Properties.

Comment: Results is of type XML.
tr.Results Like "*TestCurrent*" does not work

Comment: What do you mean with XML, is the type of that property String? Make sure you use the * in front and after TestCurrent.

Comment: The type of the column is XML. In sql management studio the type is XML(.)
I have tried with both % and * in front and after TestCurrent with no success.